# "tcl\encoding\ascii.enc could not be extracted" for pyinstaller-frozen .exe - Windows

Tags: python-2.7, windows-10, pyinstaller

A Python 2.7 script frozen into .exe using pyinstaller has worked successfully for a number of users on many different Windows networks for months.

This morning, one group of users on one Windows network, and ONLY these three and ONLY this office (who has successfully run the program before), gets an error when they execute the .exe:

```
tcl\encoding\ascii.enc could not be extracted!
fopen: Permission denied
```

This makes me suspect they've suddenly changed file permissions or security on their network.  But the only place where I know ascii.enc hangs out is `C:\Python27\tcl\tcl8.5\encoding` (or similar), and they've never had a full copy of Python, just the frozen .exe.