# Error opening Python .exe files on other Windows computers

Tags: python, windows, permissions, exe, pyinstaller

I have a Python script that I wrote on my personal Windows computer. It's very, very basic and just shows a tkinter window with a couple labels. I compiled it into an .exe file using pyinstaller with the --onefile option. When I run that .exe file on that same computer, it all works just fine.

If I copy the .exe file to a coworker's computer (also Windows), running it causes the command prompt to flash an error quickly. Opening the command prompt and executing it by typing the path, this is the error I receive:

[image]

I've seen online that tcl/encoding/ascii.enc hangs out in the python installation folder. Unfortunately, installing python and/or changing permissions for these files on my coworkers' computers is simply not an option (IT is hyper-strict about this). Is there a way to navigate this error?

Comment: Relevant [tcl-encoding-ascii-enc-could-not-be-extracted-for-pyinstaller-frozen-exe-wi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51366260)

Comment: Yes, seems this is the only other mention of this specific problem on Google, and there is no answer posted.

Comment: ***`\tcl\encoding\ascii.enc`***: This file is listed by [*Trendmicro*](https://www.trendmicro.com/vinfo/us/threat-encyclopedia/malware/RANSOM_KIRK.A/) as malware. The source seems to be a Python `.exe`.

Comment: Seems to me from that source that RANSOM_KIRK.A is the malware and ascii.enc happens to be a file in that project. If it's already installed on a lot of people's computers under C: then doesn't that mean it's harmless and necessary for Python?

Comment: ***"RANSOM_KIRK.A is the malware and ascii.enc happens to be a file in that project."***: Yes. Relevant [why-is-my-python-tkinter-executable-detected-as-a-virus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60079043/why-is-my-python-tkinter-executable-detected-as-a-virus)